# How much amps (maximum) are flowing through 1000Base-T Ethernet?

Tags: current, ethernet, amperage, gigabit

How much amps (maximum) would be flowing through a 5 meter Cat 5/6 Ethernet cable with 1000Base-T speed (IEEE 802.3ab, 5-PAM coding, so voltage levels vary between +- 2V, 1V, 0V)?

Answer (score 0):

This answer https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/36730/2228 suggests 60ma. Obviously it's alternating at high speed. But what will you do with this information?

Comment: I need the information for a circuit with transistors, which is not fully designed yet. The transistor and a ethernet line would be connected in parallel so that I can pull the data stream to ground (to disconnect the ethernet connection)

Comment: Ethernet uses a transformer-isolated, balanced line which is NOT referenced to ground. A "parallel transistor pulling to ground" seems like a doubtful scheme. Furthermore introducing such a connection will likely disturb the finely-tuned balance of the data path. The actual signal current flowing through the pair is the least of your concerns.

Comment: It's not completely unworkable for short bits of ethernet on your desk, if you short both sides of a pair to the same point and call it ground.

Comment: It worked with a first test circuit (It cut off Pings and put the interface down) but I wanted to calculate the appropriate Amps and Voltages to further optimize it. Thank you for your replies :)